# Using QComboBox to select different set of widgets displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox, pyside2

I'm working on an image viewer with a toolbar on the left. As I have many measures to make but want to use most of the display for the picture and keep the toolbar thin, I would like to use `combo_box1` and `combo_box2` to select the different widgets displayed in the toolbar.

**Example 1:** if I choose `measurements set 1` in `combo_box1` I would then be able to choose between measurements `P1-P2` and `P3-P4` in `combo_box2`.

**Example 2:** if I choose `measurements set 2` in `combo_box1` I would then be able to choose between measurements `P5-P6` and `P7-P8` in `combo_box2`.

Here is the code:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGridLayout)
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtOpenGL import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

image_path_str='image.jpg'

class View(QGraphicsView):
    photo_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.photo)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path_str)
        self.photo.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = View(self)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.checkbox_P1= QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P1",self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P1_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_x, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_y, 2, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P1_x_y, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.checkbox_P2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P2",self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P2_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P2, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_x, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_y, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P2_x_y, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.combo_box1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")

        self.combo_box2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P1-P2")
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P3-P4")

        self.vertical1= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box1)
        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box2)
        self.vertical1.addLayout(self.layout_contain_P1_P2)

        self.vertical2= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical2.addWidget(self.view)

        self.horizontal= QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical1)
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical2)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image viewer")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 800)

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
w.raise_()
QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you analyze your logic, you can see that the data has the structure of a tree:

```
root
├── measurements set 1
│   ├── P1-P2
│   └── P3-P4
└── measurements set 2
    ├── P5-P6
    └── P7-P8
```

So it will be used that [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) supports as a source of information to a model, and to establish which sheet shows is used [`rootModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#rootModelIndex), in the next part I create a generic example that involves a [`QComboBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html) plus that is defined by another level in addition to observe the dependency will use a `QTreeView`.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        play = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay = QHBoxLayout()
        self.model = create_model(d)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        play.addLayout(lay)
        play.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.expandAll()

        ix = self.model.index(0, 0)
        self.combos = []
        while self.model.hasChildren(ix):
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.setModel(self.model)
            lay.addWidget(combo)
            combo.setRootModelIndex(ix)
            combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
            ix = ix.child(0, 0)
            combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_currentIndexChanged)
            self.combos.append(combo)

    def next_combo(self, combo):
        ix = self.combos.index(combo)
        if ix != len(self.combos)-1:
            return self.combos[ix+1]


    def on_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        combo = self.sender()
        combo_child = self.next_combo(combo)
        if combo_child:
            p_ix = combo.rootModelIndex()
            ix = p_ix.child(index, 0)
            combo_child.setRootModelIndex(ix)
            combo_child.setCurrentIndex(0)


def load_childrens(values, parent):
    for value in values:
        name = value["name"]
        dependencies = value["dependencies"]
        item = QStandardItem(name)
        parent.appendRow(item)
        load_childrens(dependencies, item)

def create_model(info):
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    root = QStandardItem("root")
    model.appendRow(root)
    load_childrens(info, root)
    return model


d = [{
        'name': 'measurements set 1',
        'dependencies': [
            {
                'name': 'P1-P2',
                'dependencies': [
                {
                    'name': "T1",
                    "dependencies" : []
                },
                {
                    'name': "T2",
                    "dependencies" : []
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'P3-P4',
                'dependencies': [
                {
                    'name': "T3",
                    "dependencies" : []
                },
                {
                    'name': "T4",
                    "dependencies" : []
                }

                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        'name': 'measurements set 2',
        'dependencies': [
            {
                'name': 'P5-P6',
                'dependencies': [
                {
                    'name': "T5",
                    "dependencies" : []
                },
                {
                    'name': "T6",
                    "dependencies" : []
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                'name': 'P7-P8',
                'dependencies': [
                {
                    'name': "T7",
                    "dependencies" : []
                },
                {
                    'name': "T8",
                    "dependencies" : []
                }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: 3]

In your case, the code is the following:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGridLayout, QComboBox, \
     QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QCheckBox, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QPoint, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QCursor

image_path_str='image.jpg'

class View(QGraphicsView):
    photo_clicked = Signal(QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.photo = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.photo)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(image_path_str)
        self.photo.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = View(self)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2 = QGridLayout()
        self.checkbox_P1= QCheckBox("P1",self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P1_y = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y = QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_x, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_y, 2, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P1_x_y, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.checkbox_P2 = QCheckBox("P2",self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P2_y = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P2, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y = QGridLayout()

        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_x, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_y, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P2_x_y, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.vertical1= QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = create_model(d)
        ix = self.model.index(0, 0)
        self.combos = []
        while self.model.hasChildren(ix):
            combo = QComboBox()
            combo.setModel(self.model)
            self.vertical1.addWidget(combo)
            combo.setRootModelIndex(ix)
            combo.setCurrentIndex(0)
            ix = ix.child(0, 0)
            combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_currentIndexChanged)
            self.combos.append(combo)

        self.vertical1.addLayout(self.layout_contain_P1_P2)

        self.vertical2= QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical2.addWidget(self.view)

        self.horizontal= QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical1)
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical2)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image viewer")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 800)

    def next_combo(self, combo):
        ix = self.combos.index(combo)
        if ix != len(self.combos)-1:
            return self.combos[ix+1]

    def on_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        combo = self.sender()
        combo_child = self.next_combo(combo)
        if combo_child:
            p_ix = combo.rootModelIndex()
            ix = p_ix.child(index, 0)
            combo_child.setRootModelIndex(ix)
            combo_child.setCurrentIndex(0)

def load_childrens(values, parent):
    for value in values:
        name = value["name"]
        dependencies = value["dependencies"]
        item = QStandardItem(name)
        parent.appendRow(item)
        load_childrens(dependencies, item)

def create_model(info):
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    root = QStandardItem("root")
    model.appendRow(root)
    load_childrens(info, root)
    return model


d = [{
        'name': 'measurements set 1',
        'dependencies': [
            {
                'name': 'P1-P2',
                'dependencies': []
            },
            {
                'name': 'P3-P4',
                'dependencies': []
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        'name': 'measurements set 2',
        'dependencies': [
            {
                'name': 'P5-P6',
                'dependencies': []
            },
            {
                'name': 'P7-P8',
                'dependencies': []
            }
        ],
    }]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much @eyllanesc for your precise answer!