# Multiple Dependent QComboBox

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am trying to design a set of 4 combo boxes, each having dependencies on the previous one. I can do it for 2 combo boxes but facing problems afterwards.

Here is my code for 2 combo-boxes:

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QComboBox


class RegisterStudent(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RegisterStudent, self).__init__()
        loadUi("registrationForm.ui", self)
        self._new_window = None

        # Button Clicked:
        self.registerButton.clicked.connect(self.registerButtonClicked)
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.backButtonClicked)

        # Commissionary:
        self.commissionary.addItem("---Select Commissionary---")
        self.commissionary.addItem("Bhagalpur", ["BGP", "Banka"])
        self.commissionary.addItem("Darbhanga", ["DGH", "Madhubani"])
        
        self.commissionary.activated.connect(self.districtSelector)

    def districtSelector(self, index):
        self.district.clear()
        self.district.addItems(self.commissionary.itemData(index))
```

But, I further want on selecting District, It further leds to a Sub-division combo box and then to Block combo box.

Its structure is like this:

```
Commissionary
├── Bhagalpur
|   ├── BGP
|   |   ├── SubDivBgp 1
|   |   |   ├── Block A
|   |   |   └── Block B
|   |   └── SubDivBgp 2
|   |       ├── Block C
|   |       └── Block D
│   └── Banka
|       ├── SubDivBanka1
|       |   ├── Block E
|       |   └── Block F
|       └── SubDivBanka2
|           ├── Block G
|           └── Block H
└── Darbhanga
    ├── DGH
    |   ├── SubDivDgh 1
    |   |   ├── Block I
    |   |   └── Block J
    |   └── SubDivDgh 2
    |       ├── Block K
    |       └── Block L
    └── Madhubani
        ├── SubDivMadhubani 1
        |   ├── Block M
        |   └── Block N
        └── SubDivMadhubani 2
            ├── Block O
            └── Block P
```

I want to extend the code in the same manner.

Comment: I do not understand the title change, in this answer I show for 3 dependent QComboBox so you only have to add a new branch to the dictionary that I use as a source https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430925/6622587

Comment: Yes, I am understanding what you're saying. But there you used the python code to design the combo-box and I want to use the Qt-Designer for the same. That's why I clearly mentioned it in the title too. And at the very bottom of the question, I also mentioned that the extension of the code should be in the manner shown (if possible).

Comment: My solution is applicable to QComboBox added by QtDesigner or not. I recommend you read it, understand it and implement it in your case since the logic does not depend on whether or not QtDesigner was used.

Comment: I was trying to approach the question in the manner shown in the above-mentioned code.